# using flatbuffers.Builder.Create*()

Tags: flatbuffers

I want to use `flatbuf` to save aquadtree structure. here is my `fbs` file

```
namespace com.generated;

struct Obj {
  hash:int;
  geohash:uint64;
}

table Tree {
  obj:[Obj];
  id:int;
  nodes:[Tree];
}

root_type Tree;
```

and here is the code that I am using to make objects

```
var builder = new flatbuffers.Builder(0)
var Tree = com.generated.Tree;
var Obj = com.generated.Obj;

Tree.startTree(builder);
Tree.addId(builder, builder.createInt(1));
Tree.addObj(builder, Obj.createObj(builder, 36, 42));
var offset = Tree.endTree(builder);

Tree.startTree(builder);
Tree.addId(builder, builder.createInt(1));
Tree.addObj(builder, Obj.createObj(builder, 36, 42));
offset = Tree.endTree(builder);
builder.finish(offset);
```

well in code above I have two problems, First the `builder.createInt(1)` does not exist. So I do not know how I can create an Integer. And my second problem is with the making an array of Trees, I am currently after `Tree.end` start another `Tree` with the same builder. Is this the correct way to do that?

Comment: You can use integers directly, so just use `1` instead of `builder.createInt(1)`. And no, building 2 trees won't combine them into an array for you. You'll need to hold on to both offsets, then create a vector in the parent.

Comment: @Aardappel thanks so much for your comment, I got your first answer but can you please tell me more about the second part? Thanks